# A class inheritance C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, compiler-errors, multiple-inheritance

I have a question about class inheritance.

I think following code will explain my problem:

```
struct A {
   int x;
};

struct B: A {
};

struct C: A {
};

struct D: B, C {
    D() : x(1) {}
};

int main() {
    D d;
}
```

The code does not compile.

And the question is: How can I create an instance of struct D? Thanks!

Comment: Do not post images of code, but the code in question itself here as (properly formatted) text.

Comment: Please find a way to put all necessary information into your question, otherwise your question will be useless for other readers.

Comment: Deleted my answer  πάντα ῥεῖ

Comment: @PavanChandaka Brave guy :)

Comment: you cannot initialize parent's member in constructor initializer list of child class (or struct in this case). Either assign value to x or better create a constructor for `A` that accepts `int` and use virtual inheritance

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with what you're trying to do.

1. `D` doesn't have a member named `x`, it has *two* members named `x`.  Specifically, `D::B::x` and `D::C::x`, due to multiple inheritance and a certain issue known as the [diamond problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem).  As both `B` and `C` are derived from `A`, they each contain the entirety of `A` within their definition, and thus each contains its own `A::x`.  So, when `D` derives from `B` and `C`, it contains an entire `B` and an entire `C` within itself, including their `A`s.  It looks something like this (generated with MSVC, using compiler switch [`-d1reportSingleClassLayout`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2007/05/17/diagnosing-hidden-odr-violations-in-visual-c-and-fixing-lnk2022/)):

   ```
   class D size(8):
       +---
       | +--- (base class B)
       | | +--- (base class A)
    0  | | | x
       | | +---
       | +---
       | +--- (base class C)
       | | +--- (base class A)
    4  | | | x
       | | +---
       | +---
       +---
   ```

   You should instead modify `B` and `C` to virtually inherit from A, as:

   ```
   struct B: virtual A {
   };

   struct C: virtual A {
   };
   ```

   This will cause both `B` and `C` to, instead of containing their base `A`, let it follow them around wherever they go:

   ```
   class B size(8):
       +---
    0  | {vbptr}
       +---
       +--- (virtual base A)
    4  | x
       +---

   class C size(8):
       +---
    0  | {vbptr}
       +---
       +--- (virtual base A)
    4  | x
       +---
   ```

   This, in turn, allows `D` to take one `A`, stick that `A` to its back, and tell both of them that it's *their* `A`, resolving the diamond problem and allowing them to share the same instance.

   ```
   class D size(12):
       +---
       | +--- (base class B)
    0  | | {vbptr}
       | +---
       | +--- (base class C)
    4  | | {vbptr}
       | +---
       +---
       +--- (virtual base A)
    8  | x
       +---
   ```
2. A class can only initialise its own members in the [member initialiser list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list); it isn't allowed to initialise its base classes' members.  This is because objects in C++ are constructed in steps:

   - First, any virtual bases encountered anywhere in the inheritance hierarchy are constructed.  The most-derived class is considered to be responsible for their construction.  [If the most-derived class mentions any of its virtual bases in its initializer list, that virtual base will be passed the specified parameters.  If any of the direct base classes mention any of the virtual base classes in their initializer list, it will be ignored.]
   - Then, the object's direct base classes, if any, are constructed.  Object construction rules are applied recursively, meaning that the least-derived class(es) (i.e. the one(s) at the very bottom of the inheritance hierarchy) will be constructed first.  If a direct base class has a virtual base, that virtual base is not constructed at this time.  [If the derived class mentions any of its direct base classes in its initializer list, then that base class will be passed the specified parameters.]
   - Finally, the derived class is constructed around its direct bases, and followed by its virtual bases.  Non-static data members are constructed at this time; they will be constructed with specified parameters if in the initialiser list, or otherwise default-constructed.

   Therefore, `D` should pass parameters to `A`'s constructor, so they can initialise the fields.

   ```
   struct A {
       int x;

       // If A() has no parameter specified, it sets x to 4.
       A(int x_ = 4) : x(x_) {}
   };

   struct B: virtual A {
       // If B constructs A, it tells it to set x to 3 unless otherwise specified.
       B(int x_ = 3) : A(x_) {}
   };

   struct C: virtual A {
       // If C constructs A, it tells it to set x to 2 unless otherwise specified.
       C(int x_ = 2) : A(x_) {}
   };

   struct D: B, C {
       // This will actually set D.x to 4; since D constructs A, neither B() nor C() will
       //  call A().  D() will call A() without specifying a parameter.
       // D() : B(1), C(1) {}

       // This, however, gets the job done.  Tells A to set x to 1.
       D() : A(1) {}
   };
   ```

   Then, when you construct `d`...

   ```
   int main() {
       D d;
   }
   ```

   Its member `d.x` will now be set to `1`, as intended.

   <sub>Note that if for some reason you *do* want `D` to contain two instances of `A`, and thus refrain from using virtual inheritance, you should use the first version of the constructor instead.  This way, when `d` is constructed, both `d.B::x` and `d.C::x` will be set to 1.</sub>

---

Thanks go to [curiousguy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/963864/curiousguy) for pointing out that virtual bases are actually constructed *before* direct bases, not after them as I believed.

Comment: Subobjects are always constructed before the object.

Comment: Yeah, I mentioned that in section 2 of my answer.  First an object's base classes are constructed, then its virtual bases, and finally it, with that order being applied recursively.

Comment: So you agree that a base class ctor is always called before any of its derived class ctor?

Comment: Yeah.  "First, the object's direct base classes, if any, are constructed. Object construction rules are applied recursively, meaning that the least-derived class(es) (i.e. the one(s) at the very bottom of the inheritance hierarchy) will be constructed first."

Comment: So you agree that virtual base subobjects construction is always done before any construction of a derived subobject, contrary to your description?

Comment: Everything I'd seen about it implied that direct bases are constructed before virtual ones.  Just did a test, though, and it looks like that was wrong.  I'll update this, then.  Thanks.

Comment: Funnily enough, I've done a decent amount of testing to determine how MSVC determines class layouts, out of curiosity, but I don't think I ever did any tests specifically to determine construction order.